# MQ | Channel RETRYING status

Tags: ibm-mq

I have started exploring MQ series and I noticed Sender channel in RETRYING status after SHORTRTR are exhausted. I have also noticed client applications couldn't connect to MQ when Sender channel was in RETRYING status.

1. Is my understanding correct that client applications can't connect to MQ if Sender channel is in RETRYING status?
2. What happens client start connection with MQ and Sender channel is not RUNNING?
3. Does Sender channel status matter when client is initializing MQ connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The ability for a client application to connect is almost entirely unrelated to the state of a sender channel. (I say almost because theoretically you could use up all the resources in your queue manager by having loads of retrying senders and then maybe they could affect clients).
2. When a client application makes a connection to a queue manager, the network connection is first caught by the listener, and then a running channel of type SVRCONN is started. This is a different type from a SENDER channel, and so there is no requirement to have a SENDER channel running for the client connection to be successful.
3. Sender channel status does not matter for the client to be able to connect.

Lets' try to diagnose your two problems. Look in the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG (found in the data directory under `\Qmgrs\<qm-name>\errors`) and edit your question to add the errors you see in there. There should be errors that explain why the sender channel is retrying, and some to explain why the client cannot connect.

It is possible that the problem with the client not being able to connect is because it is not even reaching the queue manager machine - in which case there will be nothing about that in the queue manager error log. In this case, you should also look in the AMQERR01.LOG on the client machine, this time in the data directory just under the errors folder (as no queue manager name there). You should also have seen some sort of error message or MQRC Reason code from the client application - you should tell us that too.